# How to figure out if mule flow message processing is in progress

Tags: mule

I have a requirement where I need to make sure only one message is being processed at a time by a mule flow.Flow is triggered by a quartz scheduler which reads one file from FTP server every time

My proposed solution is to keep a global variable "FLOW_STATUS" which will be set to "RUNNING" when a message is received and would be reset to "STOPPED" once the processing of message is done.

Any messages fed to the flow will check for this variable and abort if  "FLOW_STATUS" is "RUNNING".

This setup seems to be working , but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Is there any best practices around this or any inbuilt mule helper functions to achieve the same instead of relying on global variables

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a more simple solution would be to set the maxActiveThreads for the flow to 1.  In Mule, each message processed gets it's own thread.  So setting the maxActiveThreads to 1 would effectively make your flow singled threaded.  Other pending requests will wait in the receiver threads.  You will need to make sure your receiver thread pool is large enough to accommodate all of the potential waiting threads.  That may mean throttling back your quartz scheduler to allow time process the files so the receiver thread pool doesn't fill up.  For more information on the thread pools and how to tune performance, here is a good link:  http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Tuning+Performance

Comment: Thanks Matt!.Would that mean my flow processing should be synchronous so that the reciever thread is released only after all processing is done. I was using VM queues to take advantage of clustering in my flows. I believe that would end up releasing the reciever thread early on

Comment: Mule will use three thread pools for each flow.  The receiver pool, the processing pool, and the dispatch pool.  When new messages come in to the Mule server for a flow, the a new receiver thread is started for that message.  If there are no threads left in the receiver pool the server will block and wait for one.  That's when you start to have performance issues.  The threads in the receiver pool will wait for a thread in the processing pool to open up and then pass the message on for processing.  In a clustered environment, Mule will look for threads on any available server in the cluster.

Comment: I have to lock down the flow until the message processing is completed. Since I am using VM queues in between, I am assuming the receiver thread will hand over messages to threads from processing pool for VM queues and will return to the receiver pool. This will imply that the server can use that thread to receive another message, while the previous message processing is still in progress.So having maxActiveThreads=1 for receiver thread profile wont help in my usecase. Please correct me if my assumption is wrong. I am guessing using the global variable is only way forward.